# Can't call menu in iOS simulator using command+D

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I've being using iOS simulator for some time and always used command+D for calling debug menu. But now something happend and menu is not appeared after command+D click.

Who knows what may happend with simulator?

I mean this menu
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are under Debug scheme , if you are under scheme, please provide your react native version, 0.43 pre-release version has a bug about this .

Comment: how to check if I'm under Debug scheme? @yifan_z

Comment: At the right of Stop button in the Left Corner of XCode, click your project name you will see 'Edit Scheme',  make sure your Build Configuration is set to Debug. @Dmitry